# Nvidia GTS-450 black screen error

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-geforce

I installed nvidia-390 and I got black after boot. and did purge of it in recovery mode.

my Nvidia: GTS-450 
I used additional drivers after adding ppa

in short I followed this. no error was occured while installing.

what can I do?

```
log_file: /var/log/gpu-manager.log
last_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
new_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-was-loaded file
can't access /opt/amdgpu-pro/bin/amdgpu-pro-px
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/4.18.0-17-generic/updates/dkms
Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/4.18.0-17-generic/updates/dkms
Is nvidia loaded? no
Was nvidia unloaded? no
Is nvidia blacklisted? no
Is intel loaded? no
Is radeon loaded? no
Is radeon blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu loaded? no
Is amdgpu blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu versioned? no
Is amdgpu pro stack? no
Is nouveau loaded? yes
Is nouveau blacklisted? no
Is nvidia kernel module available? no
Is amdgpu kernel module available? no
Vendor/Device Id: 10de:dc4
BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
Is boot vga? yes
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "nouveau"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "nouveau"
Found "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "nouveau"
output 0:
    card0-HDMI-A-1
output 1:
    card0-VGA-1
Number of connected outputs for /dev/dri/card0: 2
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "nouveau"
Does it require offloading? no
last cards number = 1
Has amd? no
Has intel? no
Has nvidia? yes
How many cards? 1
Has the system changed? No
Single card detected
Nothing to do
```